# Selling options

Tags: options

When selling an option after you bought it (not writing one) how easily are orders filled for large quantities of contracts ($25,000+) Do these sell orders usually get filled easily or not at all?

Comment: Can you tell us which stock you had in mind?  (Just BTW: please note that if you have "invented" the idea that you can buy thin options and make a billion dollars, just completely forget it, "they" are all over this and it will never work.)

Comment: @Fattie - All you need to make a pile of money with options is one stellar pick.  It's the other 99.99999 percent of one's option trades that's the problem ;->)

Comment: but my backtesting made billions @BobBaerker !!

Answer (score 1):

The price of the option determines what kind of size $25,000 means.  1,000 contracts at 25  cents apiece would be hard to move, even for the most liquid option series.  Much less so for 10 contracts at $25 apiece.

Another factor would be the liquidity of a stock's options.  The entire open interest for all of the options traded in some stocks is quite low  whereas the daily trading volume for some individual strike prices in heavily traded securities  like AAPL or SPY can easily be over 25,000 contracts.